# SAPUI5/OPENUI5: Bind string to JSON model and update bigger string automatically (it reads [object%20Object])

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have a model in SAPUI5, which I call Foo, and it has one key : value pair, {"BarKey", "BarValue"}. The model has been set succesfully in component1, and is propagated successfully. When component1 creates component2, component2 shows "BarValue" successfully, and when "BarValue" changes the page title also changes properly:

```
//Component 1
var oData = {"BarKey", "BarValue"};
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
this.component.setModel(oModel, "Foo");

  //Component 2
  return new sap.m.Page({
  title: {
    path: "Foo>/BarKey"
  },
  });
```

My problem is the following: I want to use "BarValue" as part of a URL to load a new model and Image source:

```
//Component 2 (continued)
var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("http://www.mywebsite.com/" + {
    path: "Foo>/BarKey"
  });
var oImage = new sap.ui.Image({src: "http://www.mywebsite.com/" + {
    path: "Foo>/BarKey"
  }});
```

This type of binding doesn't work. I want the source of the model and image to be changed when oModel1 changes. My browser console logs the following error:

**"http://www.mywebsite.com/"[object Object]" does not exist in Element sap.ui.commons.Image#__image0**

**GET "http://www.mywebsite.com/[object%20Object]" 404 (Not Found)**

How do I get the **[object%20Object]** to be read as a string, and update the entire string when part of it is changed in oModel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it with

```
var oImage = new sap.ui.Image({
    src: "http://www.mywebsite.com/{Foo>/BarKey}"
});
```

and add `data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"` to your `<script>` tag where you load the ui5

https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0c803921b1bf4b3a97a038fbd51ef542.html

---

in case that does not work you have to try a formatter

```
var oImage = new sap.ui.Image({
    src: {
        parts: [{
            path: 'Foo>/BarKey'
        }],
        formatter: function(parameter) {
            return "http://www.mywebsite.com/" + parameter;
        }
    }
});
```

https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html

---

to update the model as soon as its path changes you can use a sap.ui.model.Binding

```
var fooModel = this.getModel("Foo");
var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/" + fooModel.getParameter("/BarKey"));
var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(url);
var binding = new sap.ui.model.Binding(fooModel, "/BarKey", fooModel.getContext("/"));
binding.attachChange(function(){
    oModel2.loadData("http://www.mywebsite.com/" + fooModel.getProperty("/BarKey")));
});
```

Comment: For the sap.ui.commons.Image, the first option with complex binding works!

Comment: The jsonModel gives a similar error as before
    Failed to load resource: "http://www.mywebsite.com/%7BFoo%3E/BarKey%7D"

The second option also doesn't work for the model, but it doesn't return an error.

Comment: then try it with the parts-array i added to the second option, might be that the formatter needs that

Comment: It still does not work. 
new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel only takes a string when it is initialized, whereas an Image can bind to 'src', perhaps this is part of the reason?
when I do oImage.setSrc("http://www.mywebsite.com/{Foo>/BarKey}") it also does not work.

Comment: sorry, did not see your first comment, when you want to load a new model as soon as the Foo-model is updated you can bind a listener to the Foo-model. give me one minute, i add it to the answer

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly! 
Minor changes: 
getParameter should be getProperty
load should be loadData

var fooModel = this.getModel("Foo");
var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/" + fooModel.getProperty("/BarKey"));
var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(url);
var binding = new sap.ui.model.Binding(fooModel, "/BarKey", fooModel.getContext("/"));
binding.attachChange(function(){
    oModel2.loadData("http://www.mywebsite.com/" + fooModel.getProperty("/BarKey")));
});